# How can I access request object in django model admin change_form.html?

Tags: python, django

I wish to access the currently logged in user while overriding the `change_form.html` for a django model in my project. I want to access the `request.user.username`  in this form. How do I access this. I do not want to write a custom view for the same. In this template I wish to access it as `{{ request.user.username }}`. How do I do it? I am using Django version 1.6.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add request to context:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
 ...
 'django.core.context_processors.request',

)
```

Comment: P.S. this is in django settings

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1134625/michael-plakhov Thx a ton. Also we need to put 'django.core.context_processors.auth' into TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS